# Is the Italian town Empoli from Greek ἐμπολή, "merchandise?"

Tags: ancient-greek, italian

Is the italian town-name "Empoli" related to the greek word "ἐμπολή", meaning merchandise, or gain from merchandise?
I met "εμπολή" in the form of "ἐξεμπολημένων", in Herodotus 1.1.3 "ἐξεμπολημένων σφι σχεδόν πάντων".
I also wonder whether the word "emporium", greek "ἐμπόριον", i.e., trade, is of relevance here.
Sources available to me are unclear on the above, so any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The [Italian wikipedia page](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empoli) has a whole section about the etymology of the name. Long story short: many etymologies, including emporium, limpidus, and in portu, have been proposed.

Comment: You might consult "Storia Di Empoli (Classic Reprint)" ( December 2018) by Luigi Lazzeri, inaccessible to me. But your conjecture appears quite sound, for market, sale: τὰν [δεκάταν δωσεῖ]ν τῷ Ἀσκλ[απ]ιῷ τᾶς ἐμπολᾶς τῶν ἰχθύων... Beekes guesses <IE ? *kwel- .  In Catalonia,  you could find [Empúries ⟶ Ampurias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empúries) in the same spirit.

Comment: Indeed, [this ref](https://2017.gonews.it/2016/02/24/il-nome-empoli-deriva-da-portus/) argues the original name Portus was doctored!